# Solving limit using taylor series and little-o

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have been trying to find the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{e^{(x+y)^2}-\cos(x^2+y^2)-2xy}{x^2+y^2-\sin(x-y)^2+2xy}$$ using taylor series and little-o notation for the "remainder", and am stuck on where to proceed. Did I make some arithmetic error or am I missing something big here? Thanks!

Observe that: $$e^{(x+y)^2} = 1+(x+y)^2+o(x+y)^2$$, $$\cos(x^2+y^2) = 1+o(x^2+y^2)$$, and $$\sin^2(x-y) = \left(x-y +o(x-y)^2\right)^2 = (x-y)^2 + o(x-y)$$

With this, I got:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2+y^2+o(x+y)^2+o(x^2+y^2)}{4xy+o(x-y)} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2+y^2+o(2x^2+xy+y^2)}{4xy+o(x-y)}$$

I don't really feel too confident in this result, and I'm not really sure where to go from here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But I think the limit does not exist as $(x, 0) \to (0, 0)$.

Comment: Calculate and compare $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x,x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x,-x)$.